# Startup ejb bean does not work

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, cdi

I am trying to do something at startup using a startup ejb. But my bean is never called.

This is my bean:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
@Startup
public class StartupBean {

    @PostConstruct
    public void doSomething(){
        System.out.println("why??");
    }

}
```

I am using jboss 7.1.1.

What am i doing wrong? You can find my source code at bitbucket: https://bitbucket.org/cremersstijn/jee/src/9e22ed2b798a/simple-startup-bean

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're importing the wrong Singleton. If you want to create a singleton session bean, use javax.ejb.Singleton.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Singleton.html
vs.
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Singleton.html

Comment: I would never spotted that. Thank you very much!