# startup class in Weld

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss-weld, weld

I am trying to define a startup class for my application in Weld CDI with @Singleton and @Startup annotations (running on tomcat 7), but my PostConstruct method is never called.

Here is my Startup class:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import se.raindance.squid.core.domain.SquidSettings;


@Singleton 
@Startup
public class InitSquid {

  @Inject   
  private Logger log;  

  @Inject
  EntityManager entityManager;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {

    System.out.println("startup!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! InitSquid");
    // Init Rainlets
InitRainlets initRainlets = new InitRainlets(entityManager);
    initRainlets.init();

    initSquidSettings();    
  }

  private void initSquidSettings() {
    List<SquidSettings> settingsList = (List<SquidSettings>) entityManager
        .createQuery(
            "select squidsettings from SquidSettings squidsettings")
        .getResultList();

    if (settingsList.size() == 0) {
        log.info("No SquidSettings entity exists in system, creating one");

        SquidSettings settings = new SquidSettings();
        settings.setSubledgerRestResourceURI("http://localhost:8080/subledger-webapp/resteasy/");
        entityManager.persist(settings);
    }
  }

}
```

I tried the hints which I found in these two posts
[Startup POJO with WELD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347516/startup-pojo-on-a-weld-seam3-application) and [Startup EJB doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204130/startup-ejb-bean-does-not-work) but neither helped

Comment: Could you please post the `import` section of your `java class`?

Comment: I updated java class with all imports

Comment: Pease try to remove `javax.ejb.Startup` and `javax.ejb.Singleton` and use only the `javax.inject.Singleton`. Please do not mix `EJB` and `CDI`.

Comment: But I want to create a class to run at the server startup. Can I run a singleton class in server startup without using Startup annotation !?

Comment: I have the same issue.  Don't know how you're getting on with this, but in my case `javax.inject.Singleton` DOES NOT start when Tomcat starts.  It only starts after the resource into which the Singleton is injected has been started.

Answer (score 2):

You can not use the @Startup or @javax.ejb.Singleton annotations on a CDI bean: those annotations are meant for EJB's. And EJB's won't work on (plain) Tomcat. If you want to run an EE application on Tomcat, take a look at the [TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/apache-tomee.html) project.

However, there's an [AfterDeploymentValidation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/AfterDeploymentValidation.html) event that's thrown after everything has been deployed. You can write an observer method to act on that event, as shown in this blog post here:

- [Eager CDI beans](http://ovaraksin.blogspot.nl/2013/02/eager-cdi-beans.html)