# Why Weld says "Injection into Listeners is not supported" on Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, resteasy, weld

I have a web project using Resteasy (which in turn uses Weld) and is deployed to Tomcat 7.0.22 (I put the specific version here in case this issue is particular to this version).

I have a ServletContextListener that looks like this:

```
@WebListener
public class ApplicationInitialisationListener implements ServletContextListener {
    // create a logger here        

    @Inject
    HealthCheck healthCheck;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        if (healthCheck == null) {
            log.error("healthCheck is null");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    }
}
```

After deploying to Tomcat, `healthCheck is null` was logged, and I also noticed this line in the log:

```
<2013-11-13 13:27:40,191> <pack> INFO pool-2-thread-1 org.jboss.weld.environment.tomcat7.Tomcat7Container - Tomcat 7 detected, CDI injection will be available in Servlets and Filters. Injection into Listeners is not supported
```

**Question 1**: why is CDI injection not available in Listeners?

I looked into this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13504763/842860), and it says `Load on startup via @Startup. There is currently no equivalent to this in CDI.`

**Question 2**: is the issue described in Question 1 a consequence of this?

**Question 3**: I am using `org.jboss.weld.servlet:weld-servlet:1.2.0.Beta1`.  Is there any update on startup support in later versions?

**Related Questions I Looked**
[startup class in Weld](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16413997/842860)

Comment: As for question 3: Note that the message says it it not supported by _CDI_ i.e. the CDI spec doesn't define that. This might be added to a future version and thus to any version of Weld which implements that future CDI version.

Comment: @Thomas CDI isn't specific to servlets so it won't define anything related to injecting in a Java EE environment. This is a weld and JSR 299 feature .

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis ah, yes you're right. συγνώμη :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a workaround I discovered that can inject CDI beans when an application starts.

The requirement of the problem can be summarized as:

1. inject a CDI bean when the application starts
2. do something with the bean

Solution outline line:

1. Create a WebListener that calls `BeanManager.fireEvent(new SomeDummyEvent())`
2. Create an ApplicationScoped bean that responds to `SomeDummyEvent` and injects the CDI bean

Example code:

```
@WebListener
public class ApplicationInitialisationListener implements ServletContextListener {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(ApplicationInitialisationListener.class);

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        BeanManager beanManager = lookUpBeanManager();
        if (beanManager != null) {
            beanManager.fireEvent(new SomeDummyEvent());
            LOG.info("beanManager fired SomeDummyEvent.");
        } else {
            LOG.error("beanManager is null.  Cannot fire startup event.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    }

    public BeanManager lookUpBeanManager() {
        try {
            // See reference below about how I came up with this
            InitialContext iniCtx = new InitialContext();
            BeanManager result = (BeanManager) iniCtx.lookup("java:comp/env/BeanManager");
            return result;
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            LOG.error("Could not construct BeanManager.", e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static class SomeDummyEvent implements Serializable {
    }
}
```

---

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class InitializationResourceBean {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(InitializationResourceBean.class);

    @Inject
    HealthCheck healthCheck;

    public void listen(@Observes ApplicationInitialisationListener.SomeDummyEvent event) {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // Do something with healthCheck
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        // Do some other thing with healthCheck
    }
}
```

References:

http://struberg.wordpress.com/tag/cdi/

Answer (score 0):

Now,  all this is much easy to do with deltaspike servlet module

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class InitializationResourceBean {

 @Inject
 HealthCheck healthCheck;

  public void onCreate(@Observes @Initialized ServletContext context) {
    //Do initialisation stuff here.
    if(HealthCheck != null) {
      ;
    }
  }
  public void onDestroy(@Observes @Destroyed ServletContext context) {
    System.out.println("Destroyed ServletContext: " + context.getServletContextName());
  }

}
```

http://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/servlet.html

Answer (score 0):

From: http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest-master/en-US/html/environments.html#_tomcat

"Tomcat 7 and 8 are supported. Context activation/deactivation and dependency injection into Servlets and Filters works out of the box. Injection into Servlet listeners works on Tomcat 7.0.50 and newer."

So perhaps you can upgrade your Tomcat?